# Example to show/hide data with buttons/checkbox in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I was wondering if there is a way to show/hide series, based on either buttons or checkbox

I would like to have all my data in one big plot, but to not make it too cluttered, I would like to decide at runtime what data to display.

Is this possible? Is there an example that I can use as template? I have about 12 different data sets; which means that I need also to figure out how to load different data from different files, without write 12 different get data functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts has an API call for doing exactly what you want. The call you want is series.hide or series.show.

For example, the following code (from the highchars own examples) will toggle a series on an off:

```
    var series = chart.series[0];
    if (series.visible) {
        series.hide();
        $button.html('Show series');
    } else {
        series.show();
        $button.html('Hide series');
    }
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.show

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-hide/

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I need to read the API docs too; I was just reading the material on the site, which has a lots of examples but I suppose it won't include everything. So the chart.series dictate which one you hide? with [0] as the first one from the top, or there is a way to give to each series a name, so you say chart.series[seriesA]?

Comment: The series are numbered in the order you defined them in the original chart. You could keep an array of names vs. series number when you create the chart.